# A better way to extract lots of files from zip archive in bash

Tags: bash, zip

I have a zip archive with lots of files and a plaintext file with list of files (~10000 items), that I need to extract from that archive using bash.

What is the best way to perform that operation?
Obvious way is to run unzip for each line of file, but it looks to be very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running `unzip` on each file, you can run on the entire list of files by feeding the plaintext file as input:

```
unzip -j MyZipFile.zip <<<textfile
```

Comment: On macosc '-j' is ``junk paths`` is that not the same on your system ? Therefore that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I don't have to access to the machine that I tested it on :) I am at work now where I use different Linux, not sure if there's a difference in `zip` across flavours. But you can just ignore -j and `zip MyZipFile.zip <<<file` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip supports to specify which files to extract:

```
unzip archive.zip file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ...
```

But this won't work for 10000 items. You can split your list of files into chunks of 100 and run unzip with them, this would be a faster implementation than extracting each file for itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xargs with the `-a` option to read its arguments from a file. Probably also use a flag to limit the amount of arguments to an appropriate amount to ensure there aren't too many for the shell to handle if there is such a limitation.